# How to stop object being used as a camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I accidentally turned on 'use object as camera' by pressing `ctrl + numpad 0` and now I can't get it to stop doing that. I deleted all the cameras, and then created a new one, and still it keeps trying to use that object as a camera, and I can't get Blender to switch to a different camera.

I'm adding the file in case there is something glitchy here.

[image]

Comment: If this *is* something a bit glitchy, i seem to have a minor superpower of making Blender do slightly glitchy things.

Comment: Select newly created camera and press `Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0`, or in the *Properties Window* > *Scene* Tab choose wich is the active camera for that scene.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos ok, under that tab i was able to delete that camera. The shortcut with Alt wouldn't do it because my version of Ubuntu thinks Alt is an OS command. Thank you.

Comment: Not a Linux user myself so not sure, but I think it can be changed in preferences to something else like the Meta key it should be

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate, but i searched for 'object as camera' and the dupe didn't pop up. I added the tags 'camera' and '3d-view', i don't know what else might help. (Well, i guess it being marked as a dupe helps...)

Comment: @kimholder in linux I change the keyboard shortcuts so that the OS doesn't use Ctrl or Alt, but I map them to use the windows  (super) key. That way they do not interfere with the normal operation of blender.

Comment: @cegaton yeah, i did finally go find that and changed a bunch of things. This key combo was actually one of only 2 or 3 that was an issue.